# Cannot make a static reference to the non-static field student

Tags: java

I am working on a project that creates a partially filled array of type Student that will never exceed more than 100,000 Student objects. I am trying to code the "list" portion, which should print out all of the students, in whatever order the array is in.

I have been unable to get as far as compiling due to static reference issues. I am trying to use the print() method, which has already been created in the second file, but am unable to do so.

Here is the code I have so far:

```
import java.util.Scanner; // for keyboard access


public class Lab6 {
final int LENGTH = 100001;
private Student[] student = new Student[LENGTH];
private int currSize;

/**
 * promptMenu - dumps the menu to the screen and gets the user's selection 
 *       from the Scanner (usually keyboard), returning it
 * @param usingInputStream - where to place the menu text (usually
 * @return caharacter representing the user's (lowercased) selection
 */
public static char promptMenu(Scanner usingInputStream)
{
    // dump the menu ...
    System.out.println("Choose one:");
    System.out.println("  (L)ist all students.");
    System.out.println("  (A)dd a student.");
    System.out.println("  (R)ead many students from file.");
    System.out.println("  Sort Students by (F)inal exam score.");
    System.out.println("  Sort Students by final a(V)erage.");
    System.out.println("  Sort Students by (N)ame.");
    System.out.println("  (Q)uit.");

    // get the user's request ...
    System.out.print("===>");
    return Character.toLowerCase(usingInputStream.next().charAt(0));        
}
public Lab6()
{
student = new Student[LENGTH];
}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    // allow for keyboard input
    Scanner kbd = new Scanner(System.in);

    char choice; // holds the user's chosen option

    // repeat until the user quits. 
    do
    {
        // print menu and get user's selection form menu 
        choice = promptMenu(kbd);

        // based on user's choice, do something ....
        switch(choice)
        {

        /***************************************************************************
         * YOU WILL WANT TO ADD CODE FOR EACH OF CASES l, a, r, f, v, and n  !!!!! *
         ***************************************************************************/

        case 'l':  // list array contents in current ordering (if any)
            if(student != null)
            {
                for(int i=0; i<currSize; i++)
                student.toString();
                System.out.print(student);
            }
            else
                System.out.println("The array is empty.");
            break;

        case 'a':  // prompt user to add a single student and data from the keyboard
            System.out.print("Please add a single student and data from the keyboard: ");

            student = new Student[kbd.nextInt()];

            for(int i=0; i< student.length; i++)
                student[i] = kbd.nextInt();
            break;
        case 'r':  // read data from file
            break;
        case 'f':  // sort data by final exam score (numerically high to low)
            break;
        case 'v':  // sort data by final average (numerically high to low)
            break;
        case 'n':  // sort data by student name (alphabetically low to high)
            break;

        case 'q':  // do nothing ...
            break;  
        default:   // uh, oh ... user gave a bad input. 
            System.out.println("Bad choice ("+choice+") try again!");
        }
    }
    while (choice!='q'); // if user selected quit, then get out of loop.

    // print terminating message (so user knows program has not "hung". 
    System.out.println("Thank you for using student record keeper!");
}
```

}

//Here are other methods that I was given in a separate file:

```
import java.util.Scanner;  //code uses Scanner class

public class Student {

private String name;  // student name (no spaces)
private int exam1;    // student exam #1 score
private int exam2;    // student exam #2 score
private int finalExam;// student final exam score

/**
 * Constructor for Student class, given a student's pertinent data 
 * @param studentName    - first name of student, as a String.
 * @param exam1Score     - student's score on exam #1
 * @param exam2Score     - student's score on exam #2
 * @param finalExamScore - student's score on final exam
 */
public Student(String studentName, 
               int exam1Score, int exam2Score, int finalExamScore)
{
    name = new String(studentName); // don't want reference copy
    exam1 = exam1Score;
    exam2 = exam2Score;
    finalExam = finalExamScore;
}   

/**
 * Constructor for Student class, to be read from a Scanner. The Scanner
 *   could be the keybard or an open file, etc...
 *   
 * @param s  - the Scanner from which to read a student's data. 
 * 
 * NOTE: very important that data is provided in the order:
 *    name   exam1    exam2    final
 */
public Student(Scanner s)
{
    // for each instance varaiable, just read the associated data from the Scanner
    name = s.next();
    exam1 = s.nextInt();
    exam2 = s.nextInt();
    finalExam = s.nextInt();
}

// Accessors

/**
 * getName 
 * @return the Student's name
 */
public String getName() {return name;}
/**
 * getExam1
 * @return the Student's score on exam #1
 */
public int getExam1() {return exam1;}
/**
 * getExam2
 * @return the Student's score on exam #2
 */
public int getExam2() {return exam2;}
/**
 * getFinal
 * @return the Student's score on the final exam
 */
public int getFinal() {return finalExam;}
/**
 * getAvergae
 * @return the Student's overall average
 */
public double getAverage()
{
    double avg = (2.0/7)*exam1 + (2.0/7)*exam2 + (3.0/7)*finalExam;
    return avg;
}

// Mutators

/**
 * setName
 * @param toName the new name for the student
 */
public void setName(String toName) {name=new String(toName);/*again, don't want reference copy*/}
/**
 * setExam1
 * @param toScore the new exam1 score
 */
public void setExam1(int toScore) {exam1=toScore;}
/**
 * setExam2
 * @param toScore the new exam2 score
 */
public void setExam2(int toScore) {exam2=toScore;}
/**
 * setFinal
 * @param toScore the new final exam score
 */
public void setFinal(int toScore) {finalExam=toScore;}

//utility methods

/**
 * toString
 * @return String representing the Student data. Suitable for use when listing students.
 * 
 * note that adding a toString() method to any class allows you to use an object of that
 *   anywhere a String could go. The most common place for such is when printing, and
 *   the result would be that what is printed is what is returned by the toString method.
 *   So, the following code:
 *       Student almostPerfect = new Student("Perfection", 99, 98, 100);
 *       System.out.println(almostPerfect);
 *   would print something like:
 *                              Perfection:   99   98  100   99.14
 */
public String toString()
{
    String result = String.format("%40s:%5d%5d%5d%8.2f", 
                                  name, exam1, exam2, finalExam,
                                  getAverage());
    return result;
}

/**
 * print - simply dumps the STudent to the screen, using format found above in toString()
 */
public void print()
{
    System.out.print(this);
}
```

}

Comment: Would you mind indicating where in your code this is happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh dear, I am sorry your code is really messy and out of place. Perhaps start using an IDE (Eclipse?).

Either way this line is the issue

```
private Student[] student = new Student[LENGTH];
// it needs to be changed to static since its in the main method and that is a static
private static Student[] student = new Student[LENGTH];
```

Although I really would recommend that you look into what the static modifier does... and how to properly initialize a static object.

I'll try to give a quick rundown on static modifiers,

1) A static method can be called from any other class depending on visibility restrictions (private, public, protected, default). To call a static method from another class with the correct access you can do NAMEOFCLASSWHEREMETHODIS.METHODNAME();

2) The static method/Object can be called because it doesn't need an instance of the class. So theres no need to do CLASSNAME classn = new CLASSNAME();the draw back is that the static objects are initialized at start time.

I would continue but there are better guides then me out there. Please look it up and continue working hard on your code! Remember get an ide, COUGH https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/

Edit: 
In Student.java

```
 @Override
public String toString() {
   return this.name + " " + this.score (and so on) ...; 
}
```

Then you can go in and do something like

```
System.out.println(student);
```

or if you wanted to print the array

```
for(Student s: student) 
   System.out.println(s)
```

Comment: I fixed it, and now the major issues have gone away. (BTW I am using Eclipse, but I didn't know how to upload separate files to here, so I merged the two together. I apologize for the mess. Anyhow, now I tried to call the print method from the Student class (print()), but I am unable to do so with the reason being "Cannot invoke print() on the array type Student[]". Do you have any idea why that may be?

Comment: You need to override print method. The standard Object.print() isnt going to work you need to override it for proper output. Example on edit.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are trying to use a non-static field (student) inside a static method (your main method):

```
        student = new Student[kbd.nextInt()];
```

In this case you must make your variable student a static variable so the main method can make use of if.
private **static** Student[] student = new Student[LENGTH]; 
There are some simple rules for static and non-static variables and methods:
 1. Static methods can ONLY access static variables (e.g the ones declared with the static modifier). The main method is ALWAYS static so any variable you intend to use inside of it must be declared static.
 2. Non-static methods can access both type of variables static and non-static.